# What does it change between this two way of declaring a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning, I'm studing the SQL, and today I've found two ways of declaring a foreign key (for MySQL). I'd like to know what does it change between that two syntax and why should I need to set a name for the foreign key (Syntax 2).

Syntax 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idtest` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`desc` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`idtest`) REFERENCES `test` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Syntax 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idtest` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`desc` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK_1` (`idtest`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idtest`) REFERENCES `test` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thank you!

Comment: They are just 2 ways of expressing the same thing. The first way of expressing the FK will be implemented as the second form you typed there, in other words, they will be implemented as a constraint.

Comment: @Icarus It is a constraint regardless of whether you have the `CONSTRAINT` keyword there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally there is no difference.

- The first example does name the Foreign Key, but it's the RDBMS that does the naming.
- The second example lets you expressly name the Foreign Key yourself.

The ability to name the Foreign Key yourself allows you to communicate to other developers what the key means, and conform to standard naming conventions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The second syntax enables you to delete, modify or reuse that constraint at some point in the future.

The first syntax can not be changed as it is in the definition of the table.

Answer (score 1):

The optional `CONSTRAINT` keyword allows you to specify a name for the foreign key. Without it, a name will be generated automatically.

This name can be seen in the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_CONSTRAINTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html) table.